# Using lapply with parse() function

Tags: r, lapply

I want to `parse()` through a list of conditions using lapply, to then be able to use them as a filter for a data set. Consider this for instance :

```
library(ggplot2)
argList <- list(c("mpg"), "manufacturer == \"audi\" ", "year > 2002")
argList <- lapply(argList, FUN = parse, text = argList)
data <- do.call(filter, argList)
```

The `parse()` function takes a `text = " "` argument for input, representing the string of character to be parsed. I can't get `lapply()` to use each element of the list instead of the whole list. 
Indeed, `lapply(argList, FUN = parse, text = argList)` returns

```
[[1]]
expression(mpg, manufacturer == "audi", year > 2002)

[[2]]
expression(mpg, manufacturer == "audi", year > 2002)

[[3]]
expression(mpg, manufacturer == "audi", year > 2002)
```

instead of

```
[[1]]
mpg

[[2]]
manufacturer == "audi"

[[3]]
year > 2002
```

Comment: Maybe you want `foo <- function(x) parse(text = x)` instead of `parse` itself, since `text` isn't the first argument to `parse`.

Comment: How about `lapply(argList, function(x) parse(text = x))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are passing the entire `argList` to `parse()` and not using the value thats passed via the `lapply`. Also you'll need to unbox the expression to get the call. Try

```
argList <- lapply(argList, FUN = function(x) parse(text=x)[[1]])
argList
# [[1]]
# mpg
# 
# [[2]]
# manufacturer == "audi"
# 
# [[3]]
# year > 2002
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also use `parse_expr` from `rlang`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
do.call(filter, map(argList, parse_expr))
# A tibble: 9 x 11
#  manufacturer model      displ  year   cyl trans drv     cty   hwy fl    class
#  <chr>        <chr>      <dbl> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>
#1 audi         a4           2    2008     4 manu… f        20    31 p     comp…
#2 audi         a4           2    2008     4 auto… f        21    30 p     comp…
#3 audi         a4           3.1  2008     6 auto… f        18    27 p     comp…
#4 audi         a4 quattro   2    2008     4 manu… 4        20    28 p     comp…
#5 audi         a4 quattro   2    2008     4 auto… 4        19    27 p     comp…
#6 audi         a4 quattro   3.1  2008     6 auto… 4        17    25 p     comp…
#7 audi         a4 quattro   3.1  2008     6 manu… 4        15    25 p     comp…
#8 audi         a6 quattro   3.1  2008     6 auto… 4        17    25 p     mids…
#9 audi         a6 quattro   4.2  2008     8 auto… 4        16    23 p     mids…
```

#### data

```
argList <- list(c("mpg"), "manufacturer == \"audi\" ", "year > 2002")
```

Comment: Thanks for this very elegant solution albeit a little different than what I had in mind first ! Strangely enough, tidyverse does not seem to always import rlang so for this to work you may have to load `library(rlang)`first.